# Detect My Second Account

Tags: internet, ip, user-accounts, remote-access

Let's say I was banned from a website, and I want to create a new account and use it without the 2 accounts being linked.

1. **Different Browser Is Used.**
2. **IP is different.**
3. **Java + Flash disabled.**
4. **Different Name.**

What else can I do ? Can they detect my router's MAC, or network card
MAC?

Comment: Use tor, and wonder why you were banned at first place.

Comment: That's a very very relevant question.

Comment: This depends on how the website is designed.  Realistically a browser will never submit your MAC address.  If the website was a Java applet then it could outside of that `HTML5` and `Javascript` don't have that capability.  Of course there is a ton of information that Javascript does have access to and most browser fingerprinting is done in Javascript.

Comment: This question seems to be walking a fine line between "How does (how can) this technology work?" (on topic) and "How can I violate the Terms of Service of this website (which I agreed to obey)?" (off topic).

Answer (score 1):

MAC addresses are used for internal routing, your MAC address is forgotten after it reaches your router, your routers MAC address is forgotten after it reaches the next hop (I.e. the one shown in tracert/traceroute).

Your steps should be enough, you probably don't have to change browser, just wipe cookies.

Comment: Correct on the MAC address. However wrong on the browser. In fact, a *lot* of information can be deduced from "using the same browser" - depends how savvy the website owners are: https://panopticlick.eff.org/ - screen resolution, plugins (not extensions), even what fonts are installed on your PC can uniquely identify you.

Comment: I said probably because browser fingerprinting is usually for targeted advertising than for enforcing bans, but it could.

Comment: Depends who's doing the banning I suppose :-P